# Possible to target HTML tag that is before text within a parent element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to target the `<code>` tag in sample 1, but not sample 2:

```
Sample 1: <p><code>foo()</code> describes the function</p>
Sample 2: <p>Other text comes first, <code>bar()</code> is not at the beginning</p>
```

the `code:first-child` selector does not regard the text-node "Other text comes first" as a child element.

Any ideas, on whether I can handle this in pure CSS (I know how to do it with JS or by altering the HTML code, but that's not what is needed)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

Not with pure CSS. There is no "first node of parent element without any text before it" selector.

Even with a combination of [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and the various sibling selectors ([adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and / or [general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)), this is not possible.

In fact, a javascript solution to this would be non-trivial to author, even if using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

In the context given, I also don't think this is possible.

If you are able to manage everything within a single element (in this case, a singular `<p>` element), you can use the CSS `:first-of-type` selector, which matches every element that is the first child, of a particular type, of its parent:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.colorMe code:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="colorMe">
  <code>foo()</code> describes the function<br />
  Other text comes first, <code>bar()</code> is not at the beginning
</p>

<p>
  <code>foo()</code> describes the function<br />
  Other text comes first, <code>bar()</code> is not at the beginning
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case, only the first `code` element would be targeted with the `CSS`. You can see that in action [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G5H9IG904W9G). More info on [CSS :first-of-type selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp).

Hope this helps :)